# Using jQuery Mask Plugin on dynamic value

Tags: javascript, jquery, input, dynamic, mask

I'm trying to use [jQuery-Mask-Plugin](https://igorescobar.github.io/jQuery-Mask-Plugin/docs.html) on an input which value can be dynamic. This input can be any number with, at least, 2 digits to a maximum of 8 digits and the mask is a '-'. For example I can have '2-2', '45-8' or '9999999-8', etc.

The issue is that the mask isn't working at all. I managed to make it work using `$("#input-area input").mask("00-0");` but that way, my mask isn't dynamic.

Here's what I was trying to do:

```
var options = {
    onKeyPress: function (conta, ev, el, op) {
        var masks = ['0-0', '00-0', '000-0', '0000-0', '00000-0', '000000-0', '0000000-0', '0000000-0'];
        if(conta.length == 2){
            var mask = masks[0];
        } else if(conta.length == 3){
            var mask = masks[1];
        } else if(conta.length == 4){
            var mask = masks[2];
        } else if(conta.length == 5){
            var mask = masks[3];
        } else if(conta.length == 6){
            var mask = masks[4];
        } else if(conta.length == 7){
            var mask = masks[5];
        } else if(conta.length == 8){
            var mask = masks[7];
        }
        $('#input-area input').mask(mask, options);
    }
}
if($('#input-area > div > input').length == 2){
          $('#input-area > div > input').mask('0-0', options);
} else if($('#input-area > div > input').length == 3){
        $('#input-area > div > input').mask('00-0', options);
} else if($('#input-area > div > input').length == 4){
        $('#input-area > div > input').mask('000-0', options);
} else if($('#input-area > div > input').length == 5){
        $('#input-area > div > input').mask('0000-0', options);
} else if($('#input-area > div > input').length == 6){
        $('#input-area > div > input').mask('00000-0', options);
} else if($('#input-area > div > input').length == 7){
        $('#input-area > div > input').mask('000000-0', options);
} else if($('#input-area > div > input').length == 8){
        $('#input-area > div > input').mask('0000000-0', options);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Searching a bit further in the docs of [Jquery Mask Plugin](https://igorescobar.github.io/jQuery-Mask-Plugin/docs.html) I found **Recursive digits**. It will be something like: `$('#input-area > div > input').mask('##0-0', {reverse: true});`

Answer (score 0):

A few things wrong here

- First of all and the most obvious is that you are initiating the
  `mask` before the input is loaded in DOM. Load the `input` first then
  the `mask`
- You are missing code: Where is the `event` that loads the dynamic input?
- You are loading your `onKeyPress` in the options?

You might want to structure your jquery as such

**HTML**

However your `keypress` is made (`click` event), make it so it passes the value of the length. Basically, load your `data-id` dynamically beforehand in the button. In my example, it is `2`

```
<button class="loadinput" data-id="2">Click</button>

<div id="input-area"><div></div></div>
```

**JQUERY**

Then in jquery load the input first, then load the `mask`

```
$(document).on('click', '.loadinput', function() {
    var this_length = $(this).attr('data-id');
    $('#input-area > div').html('<input id="thisinput" type="text">');
    if (this_length == 2) {
        $('#thisinput').mask('0-0');
    } else if (this_length == 3) {
        $('#thisinput').mask('00-0')
    }...and so on
})
```